# Can't obtain iteration 'Theme' in Rally app (2.0RC3)

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I'm modifying the [IterationSummary app from the 2.0RC3 SDK](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/releases/download/2.0rc3/2.0rc3.zip), and adding more iteration info to it.  For some reason, I am not able to retrieve the 'Theme' for the iteration, although I am able to query for other fields from the iteration object.  Starting with the sample, I simply added the following lines @192

```
{
    cls: 'theme',
    html: iteration.get('Theme')
},
```

I can get 'Name' but I can't get the 'Theme' value even though it is clearly set on the iteration, and I verified that value using the REST API to query that same iteration.  And querying other fields such as 'Name' works well. Any idea why 'Theme' is not being returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you fetch 'Theme' ?

You may see a general example that builds a grid of iterations that fall within a release (selected in the releasecombobox) that has Theme column populated as long as an iteration has a theme entered  is in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/iterations-within-release).

This example is different from the IterationSummary app because in my example I explicitly create Rally.data.wsapi.Store for Iteration object and fetch Theme.

Customizing the IterationSummary app will still require explicit fetching of Theme field, but you are correct that it is not obvious from the IterationSummary app how other fields are being fetched, e.g. State of iteration. The iteration object in that app is returned from `this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getRecord()` and if you print out that object in the console, theme will be empty. The fields that exist on `this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getRecord()` are limited and cannot be customized for performance reasons.

In order to modify this app to display Theme, the Iteration model has to be accessed and Theme fetched explicitly. Here are the steps I took to modify the app:

added getTheme function:

```
getTheme: function(){ 
            var iteration = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getRecord();
            return iteration.self.load(iteration.getId(), {
                fetch: ['Theme']
            });
        }
```

In rc3 every time when we have a record, `.self` will give its  model, so there is **no need to do this manually**:

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
    type: 'Iteration',
    //...
```

Note `fetch: ['Theme']`

Next, inside `_addContent` method `getTheme()` is called

```
return Deft.Promise.all([this.getTheme(), this.calculateTimeboxInfo()]).then({
                success: function(results) {
                    var theme = results[0].get('Theme');
```

and then finally theme variable's value is passed to:

```
{
   cls: 'theme',
   html: theme
}
```

The full code is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/modified-iteration-summary-with-theme).

Comment: Hi Nick, The answer your question is no, I'm not fetching 'Theme' specifically.  However, none of the other fields that work, e.g. Name, State, are being fetched the way you showed either. The sample you showed is very different from the IterationSummary app in 2.0RC3.  I searched through the code and can't see why the other fields are working.

Comment: I re-wrote the IterationSummary app to display iteration's theme, and updated the answer to go over some details.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  Your changes resolve my question & I will have to read up on Promises to wrap it all up.  The only thing that I would suggest, if it's not in the online help already, is to document the fact that some fields (perhaps the full list) are not fetched by default, because there's no way to figure out which fields need to be fetched.